# Xamarin - Not occupying the whole area in the screen using grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have 4 buttons in the bottom part of the screen as menus and I had used grid to show 4 buttons with same width and height and will occupy the whole screen. I have these codes but the result is not they way i wanted. It is not occupying the whole screen. Please help me how can I achieve it. Thanks.

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#BC3022" MinimumHeightRequest="20" Padding="0,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                        <Image Source="home.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="25"/>
                        <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Home</Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                        <Image Source="jobs.png" WidthRequest="40"  HeightRequest="25">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnJobsGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Jobs</Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                        <Image Source="sync.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="25"/>
                        <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Sync</Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                        <Image Source="logout.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="25">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnLogoutGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Signout</Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have the box views before and after every stacklayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your code with below code:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#BC3022" MinimumHeightRequest="20" Padding="10,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                    <Image Source="home.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="25"/>
                    <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Home</Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                    <Image Source="jobs.png" WidthRequest="40"  HeightRequest="25">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnJobsGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Jobs</Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                    <Image Source="sync.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="25"/>
                    <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Sync</Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Padding="10,2,10,2">
                    <Image Source="logout.png" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="25">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnLogoutGestureTap" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Label Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center">Signout</Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>           
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, why change to stacklayout from absolute ? This menu should remain as is in same position

Comment: You mean below of the screen?

Comment: If you want to display menu bottom of the screen then you can use VerticalOption="End". Because Absolute Layout is not preferable in Xamarin forms. It affects the performance of application. So it's good if we use it if required overlapping of layout.